# Ember: attributes of type object

Tags: ember.js, attributes, ember-data

The API I call returns data like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "5",
    "type": "person",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "John",
      "pet": {
        "typeOf": "cat",
        "petName": "Furry"
      },
      ...
```

models/person.js:

```
name: attr('string'),
pet: attr()
```

template:

```
{{input type="text" class="form-control" value=model.pet.petName}}
```

This works for name but not for pet. Do I have to create a pet model even though there's no API call for pets? Will this even work, as the API returns pet as an object attribute, and not a relationship?

Comment: just try pet: attr() - it means defining attribute with no transform.

Comment: My bad, that's what I did. Does that mean it is supposed to work, saving object attributes?

Comment: yes. that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.It will work. [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/45c15760a4292ec1d31b85ed9438e3cd?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

**routes/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findRecord('person', 5);
  }
});
```

**models/person.js**

```
import Model from "ember-data/model";
import attr from "ember-data/attr";

export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  pet: attr()
});
```

**templates/application.hbs**

```
{{input type="text" class="form-control" value=model.pet.petName}}
```

**adapters/application.js**

```
import Adapter from "ember-data/adapters/json-api";

export default Adapter.extend();
```

**serializers/application.js**

```
import Serializer from "ember-data/serializers/json-api";

export default Serializer.extend();
```

JSON API call return data:

```
{
    data: {
        type: 'person',
        id: 5,
        attributes: {
            "name": "John",
            "pet": {
                "typeOf": "cat",
                "petName": "Furry"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK thanks for the twiddle, that means my problem is elsewhere and I can rule out this concern, great!